# Python Telegrambot requires /start every time the bot is restarted

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

**I created a bot with the python-telegram-bot library and the user has the ability to navigate through the states, but when there is a bug, I need to restart the bot and when I restart the bot, the user needs to type /start again in order to communicate with the bot, instead of this, is there a method that I can let the user to continue from whichever state the user was in the bot before?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The states of [`ConversationHandler`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.conversationhandler.html) are stored in memory by default, that's true. If you want these states to be persisted across reboots of your python script, please have a look at PTBs built-in [persistency setup](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Making-your-bot-persistent).

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.

Answer (score 0):

**By adding a MessageHandler to entry_points in addition to CommandHandler, you can check whether the user has been in your program before and you can redirect the registered user without the need to type /start**

```
async def check_user_state(update: Update, context:ContextTypes):
    if user_exists:
        return MENU_EXE
    elif user_exists_is_not_active:
        return NONEACTIVE
    else:
        return START
```

> Define additional message handlers for specific states

```
def main():
    app = Application.builder().token(Token).build()
    conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[
            MessageHandler(None, check_user_state),
            CommandHandler("start", start_command)
        ],
```